# How to pass custom data in FullCalender Vue with eventDataTransform

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

I have custom data points for each event (for example event.organizer). I want this included in the calendar within the event section.

I looked over the documentation (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform), but it is pretty slacking, especially in regards to the Vue component (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue)

Can anyone assist in how the Vue Component should look? Do I need to add a prop? The following did not work.

```
import { resources, events }  from "/mockdata.js";
```

```
    <FullCalendar @eventDataTransform="eventDataTransform" :options="calendarOptions" />
```

```
export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, resourceTimelinePlugin],
        initialView: "resourceTimeline",
        initialDate: "2021-06-18",
        resources,
        events,
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    eventDataTransform: function(json) {
      console.log(json)
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found within example. https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/blob/master/vue3-typescript/src/Demo.vue#L115

```
<FullCalendar :options="calendarOptions">
    <template v-slot:eventContent='arg'>
      <i>{{ arg.event.extendedProps.organizer }}</i>
    </template>
</FullCalendar>
```